# Activate works on my Windows 10 Office 365 computer but not on another system

Tags: vba, ms-word

The attached code which is designed to open XYZ.dot file (alongside) a destination docm, activate it, copy it and then paste it into destination docm which is side by side with it. The code was recorded into a Word macro and modified a little.

It woks perfectly on my W 10, O 365, computer but hangs on the second statement 
       oAppW.Windows("R:\X\" & "XYZ.dot" & "  -  Compatibility Mode").Activate
on the destination system - which is run from a computer with W 10, O 365 also.

The requested XYZ.dot opens after the first statement but won't activate on the next -implying that this fiel / template cannot be found.

Very perplexing.

Runs on one computer but fails on an "identical" w.r.t software, computer.
Obviously not quite identical

```
oAppW.Documents.Open FileName:="R:\XYZ.dot", ConfirmConversions:=False, _
      ReadOnly:=False, AddToRecentFiles:=False, 
      PasswordDocument:="", _
      PasswordTemplate:="", Revert:=False, 
      WritePasswordDocument:="", _
      WritePasswordTemplate:="", Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, 
      XMLTransform:=""


0AppW.Windows("R:\XYZ.dot  -  Compatibility Mode").Activate

oAppW.Selection.WholeStory
oAppW.Selection.Copy

oAppW.Windows.CompareSideBySideWith "StartHeaderEmpty.docm"
oAppW.Windows("StartHeaderEmpty.docm").Activate

oAppW.Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)

oAppW.Windows("R:\XYZ.dot  -  Compatibility Mode").Activate
oAppW.ActiveWindow.Close
```

> Error 5941  Problem. The requested member of the collection does not exist.

I've googled this but cannot find a parallel situation

Comment: You are using a 0 zero  instead of a o  oo in  the line.

Comment: Instead of referring to the document by name, use a variable: `Set myDoc = oAppW.Documents.Open...`. Then work with `myDoc` as needed.

Comment: Drive`R:`(network drive?)is mapped  (same share) and has sufficent security settings on both computer?

Comment: Is the document open in _compatibility mode_ on both machines?